# hr tag is not working in firefox correctly

Tags: html, css

This is my effective code:

```css
.row {
  background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #98bf21;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-top: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 100%;
}
hr {
  display: block;
}
.row2 div {
  float: left;
}
.tblalt {
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.tblalt .left {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-right: 5px;
  width: 30%;
}
.tblalt .right {
  border-left: 1px solid #0f0f0f;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-left: 2px;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<section class="row row2">

  <h3>Albert Einstein,  1879 - 1955 </h3>

  <p>US(German-born) Physicist</p>
  <hr>
  <div class="tblalt">
    <div class="left"><b>Source</b>

    </div>
    <div class="right"><b>Quotations</b>

    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <div class="tblalt">
    <div class="left">-</div>
    <div class="right">Before God we are all equally wise and equally foolish.</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <div class="tblalt">
    <div class="left">-</div>
    <div class="right">Few people are capable of expressing with equanimity opinions which differ from the prejudices of their social environment. Most people are even incapable of forming such opinions.</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <div class="tblalt">
    <div class="left">-</div>
    <div class="right">I never teach my pupils. I only attempt to provide the conditions in which they can learn.</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <div class="tblalt">
    <div class="left">-</div>
    <div class="right">I never think of the future - it comes soon enough. Imagination is more important than knowledge ...</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <div class="tblalt">
    <div class="left">-</div>
    <div class="right">It is miracle that curiosity survives formal education.</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <div class="tblalt">
    <div class="left">-</div>
    <div class="right">It is the supreme art of the teacher to awaken joy in creative expression and knowledge.</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <div class="tblalt">
    <div class="left">-</div>
    <div class="right">Laws alone can not secure freedom of expression; in order that every man present his views without penalty there must be spirit of tolerance in the entire population.</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <div class="tblalt">
    <div class="left">-</div>
    <div class="right">Only two things are infinite, the universe and human stupidity, and I'm not sure about the former.</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <div class="tblalt">
    <div class="left">-</div>
    <div class="right">Reading, after a certain age, diverts the mind too much from its creative pursuits. Any man who reads too much and uses his own brain too little falls into lazy habits of thinking.</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</section>
```

`hr` tag is working correctly in Chrome:

[image]

But `hr` tag is not working in firefox:

[image]

My site url: http://englishact.com/Quotations/AlbertEinstein.php

Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

Comment: I just opened your link in both Chrome (43.0.2357.132) and Firefox (39.0), both displayed the _<hr>_ tag properly. How exactly would you define _'not working'_?

Comment: May be I am using earlier version of firefox.

Comment: It might be. Please update and let us know if the problem is still there.

Comment: Is there any way to work it in all version of firefox?

Comment: I'm afraid not. The tag-rendering is based on the web browser's rendering engine which may differ and have updates and upgrades throughout versions.

Comment: @AdamSmith I edited your code into your question. Stack Overflow requires all code to be in the question itself as if your link goes dead/problem solved the question will be of little use to other users experiencing your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this for `<hr>` tag.

```
hr {
clear: both;
}
```

Source: [click here](http://en.blog.improveit.com.br/articles/2008/09/27/margins-on-the-hr-tag-a-case-solved)

Comment: Why does it happen? In chrome it works fine but not in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring because the `hr` elements are actually being positioned next to the floated `.tblalt` elements.

To make the `hr` elements appear under the `.tblalt` elements you need to ensure they are set to `clear: left;` so that they clear the left floated `.tblalt` elements.

> The clear CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to
>   floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared)
>   below them. The clear property applies to both floating and
>   non-floating elements.
>
> When applied to non-floating blocks, it moves the border edge of the
>   element down until it is below the margin edge of all relevant floats.
>   This movement (when it happens) causes margin collapsing not to occur.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

```css
.row {
  background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #98bf21;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-top: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 100%;
}
hr {
  clear: left;
  display: block;
}
.row2 div {
  float: left;
}
.tblalt {
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.tblalt .left {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-right: 5px;
  width: 30%;
}
.tblalt .right {
  border-left: 1px solid #0f0f0f;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-left: 2px;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<section class="row row2">
  <h3>Albert Einstein,  1879 - 1955 </h3>
  <p>US(German-born) Physicist</p>
  <hr>
  <div class="tblalt">
    <div class="left"><b>Source</b></div>
    <div class="right"><b>Quotations</b></div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <div class="tblalt">
    <div class="left">-</div>
    <div class="right">Before God we are all equally wise and equally foolish.</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <div class="tblalt">
    <div class="left">-</div>
    <div class="right">Few people are capable of expressing with equanimity opinions which differ from the prejudices of their social environment. Most people are even incapable of forming such opinions.</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <div class="tblalt">
    <div class="left">-</div>
    <div class="right">I never teach my pupils. I only attempt to provide the conditions in which they can learn.</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <div class="tblalt">
    <div class="left">-</div>
    <div class="right">I never think of the future - it comes soon enough. Imagination is more important than knowledge ...</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <div class="tblalt">
    <div class="left">-</div>
    <div class="right">It is miracle that curiosity survives formal education.</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <div class="tblalt">
    <div class="left">-</div>
    <div class="right">It is the supreme art of the teacher to awaken joy in creative expression and knowledge.</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <div class="tblalt">
    <div class="left">-</div>
    <div class="right">Laws alone can not secure freedom of expression; in order that every man present his views without penalty there must be spirit of tolerance in the entire population.</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <div class="tblalt">
    <div class="left">-</div>
    <div class="right">Only two things are infinite, the universe and human stupidity, and I'm not sure about the former.</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <div class="tblalt">
    <div class="left">-</div>
    <div class="right">Reading, after a certain age, diverts the mind too much from its creative pursuits. Any man who reads too much and uses his own brain too little falls into lazy habits of thinking.</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `<hr>` to separate content is a bit of a hack :-)
Why not try styling the actual contents:

```
.tblalt {
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px dotted blue;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted blue;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```